# Finding difference between two vector layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, land-cover, combine

I have two vector layer land cover for 2016 and 2018. I want to get  result layer that will show changes in land cover e.g. the forest has changed into a meadow.

What option in QGIS can I use to do that?